# Accessing Jekyll collection file from subdirectories

Tags: jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

I'm still learning Jekyll, but I am trying to port our documentation over so that people can access our docs when we update them in our product. Ideally, I wanted to make this as seamless as possible. Our product docs are already laid out in .md format, and the tree looks like this:

```
├── 01_Using_The_Dashboard
│   ├── 01_Dashboard_Overview.md
│   ├── 02_Widgets_Overview.md
│   ├── 03_Pre-built_Widgets.md
│   ├── 04_Creating_your_own_widgets.md
│   ├── 05_Search_Syntax.md
│   ├── 06_Dashboard_Import_Export.md
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── add-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── controls@2x.png
│   │   ├── creating-search-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── dashboard-edit@2x.png
│   │   ├── dashboard-selector@2x.png
│   │   ├── edit-widget-field@2x.png
│   │   ├── edit-widget-filter@2x.png
│   │   ├── edit-widget-modal@2x.png
│   │   ├── edit-widget-other@2x.png
│   │   ├── edit-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── event-rate-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── lastn-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── notifications-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── resize-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── save-to-dashboard@2x.png
│   │   ├── search-results-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── system-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── tasks-widget@2x.png
│   │   ├── time-range-selector@2x.png
│   │   ├── time-range@2x.png
│   │   └── topn-widget@2x.png
│   └── index.md
├── 02_Creating_Triggers
│   ├── 01_Trigger_Page.md
│   ├── 02_Explanation_of_Actions.md
│   ├── 03_Trigger_Scripts.md
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── add-new-trigger.png
│   │   ├── add-note@2x.png
│   │   ├── execute-script@2x.png
│   │   ├── filters@2x.png
│   │   ├── issue-notification@2x.png
│   │   ├── query-bar@2x.png
│   │   ├── search-results@2x.png
│   │   ├── send-email@2x.png
│   │   └── system-settings@2x.png
│   └── index.md
├── 03_Alerts
│   ├── 01_Alerts_Overview.md
│   ├── 02_Automations.md
│   ├── 03_Trigger_Import_Export.md
│   ├── 04_Outgoing_Webhooks.md
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── add-new-trigger.png
│   │   ├── filters-hosts.png
│   │   ├── filters-severities.png
│   │   ├── outgoing_webhooks.png
│   │   ├── slack_alert.png
│   │   └── triggers.png
│   └── index.md
├── 04_Backend_Administration
│   ├── 01_Receiving_Syslog_Events.md
│   ├── 02_Sending_Email_From_The_Server.md
│   ├── 03_Archive_and_Restore.md
│   ├── 04_Server_Licensing.md
│   ├── 05_Using_TLS_Tunnels.md
│   ├── 06_Using_HTTPS.md
│   ├── 07_Backend_Configuration_Options.md
│   ├── 08_Backend_Search_Settings.md
│   ├── 09_Migrating_LogZilla_To_A_New_Server.md
│   ├── images
│   │   └── smtp.png
│   └── index.md
├── 05_Software_Notes
│   ├── 01_Development_Lifecycle.md
│   ├── 02_Release_Notes.md
│   ├── 03_LogZilla_VMWare_Image.md
│   ├── images
│   │   └── ticketflow.png
│   └── index.md
├── 06_Performance_Tuning
│   ├── 01_UDP_Buffer_Tuning.md
│   ├── 02_CPU_Frequency_Governers.md
│   ├── 03_VMWare_Performance.md
│   ├── 04_Filesystem_Performance.md
│   ├── images
│   │   └── vmware-disk-priority.png
│   └── index.md
├── 07_Receiving_Data
│   ├── 01_Receiving_SNMP_Traps.md
│   ├── 02_Cisco_IOS_Configuration.md
│   ├── 03_Receiving_Rsyslog_Events.md
│   ├── 04_Debugging_Event_Reception.md
│   ├── 05_Incoming_Webhooks.md
│   ├── 06_Receiving_Windows_Events.md
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── snare-001.png
│   │   ├── snare-002.png
│   │   ├── snare-003.png
│   │   └── snare-004.png
│   └── index.md
├── 08_Event_Correlation
│   ├── 01_Intro_to_Event_Correlation.md
│   ├── 02_Event_Correlation_Rule_Types.md
│   ├── 03_Sample_Rules.md
│   ├── 04_Correlating_Windows_Events.md
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── cisco-ec-mne.png
│   │   ├── cisco-ec-save.png
│   │   └── cisco-ec.png
│   └── index.md
├── 09_API
│   ├── 01_Using_The_API.md
│   └── index.md
└── template.html
```

I have a few hurdles:

1. The structure above of course
2. Our md files aren't using front matter, rather, we have `<!-- @@@title:Dashboard Overview@@@ -->` at the top of the markdown files. I could just do something like `perl -i -pe 's/<\!-- @@@(title:)(.*?)@@@ -->/---\n$1 $2\n---\n/g' *.md` but wasn't sure if there is a more elegant solution.
3. The image links would also have to be converted. In our files, they are done like so:`![Controls](@@path/images/controls.png)`

Can someone suggest a method I can use to make this an easily-repleatable process so that when we update our docs, they auto-update on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the structure above should be no problem. I would not add that to the "_posts" directory but directly to the root folder. It should then generate files like:

```
01_Using_The_Dashboard/01_Dashboard_Overview.html
```

If you are not happy with the permalink generated, you can always overwrite this setting in the Frontmatter.

2) I am not aware on any $x2frontmatter tooling. There is something for migrating from wordpress as far as I know. I think your perl solutions is probably the most elegant way to do such a conversion. Please also think about generating addition content, like "layout: page" or similar, otherwise you would have to maintain it afterwards.

3) Instead of @@path you can use the base url. Please see [Parkers post](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/). Please also see the [variables section](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) which might contain additional nice information for you.

Regarding your fourth question, it seems you would like to know how to autdeploy changes. Just like continous deployment. There are multiple ways to do that.

1. Here is a blog post I wrote back then to auto deploy using [rsync, crontab and shell](https://grobmeier.solutions/autodeploy-jekyll-28012014.html).
2. Here is a more detailed blog post on how to [deploying to S3](https://grobmeier.solutions/deploying-jekyll-09092015.html) (including assets).
3. There is even the option to deploy to GitHub. Please see the docs for [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

Personally I use the CloudFront/S3 option.

Comment: Ty. Question: If I have all of these directories under `_docs`, then what do I need to add to `_config.yaml` in order to make them accessible?  How do I access them in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: Why _docs and not just docs? You could loop through them using the pages variable. Just filter by path